# Rails 3 - All users stuck while someone is processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, request

We have a web-app here that makes hundreds of calculations with money and other very specific numbers. It has been developed in Rails 3, which I have not much experience.

Recently, I have noticed that even in Digital Ocean server, where it runs for production, whenever an user requests to open some page for example, that does any query to get data from the database, everyone else gets stuck until the processing finishes.

It just looks like rails is running on a "single-threaded" mode, similar to running the same scenario with Tomcat in development mode in Eclipse.

Is there any trick to make it work "multi-threaded"?

I don't see any reason or even logic for it to run like this, there's no sense in making everyone wait until the request of another user finishes.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution.

To enable Rails with WEBrick to work in a "multi-threaded" way, you'll have to simply go to the config file, and add :

# Enable threaded mode
  config.threadsafe!

After that, restart the server and the trick is done. It "solved" my problem, but ended up creating a thousand others, cause the application wasn't developed thinking about a "threadsafe" scenario, which means, that everytime I try to run similar requests at the same time, the application mixes up everything in memory, crashing.

Well, one problem at once!

The original from this topic is solved.